# Динамический массив std::string

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужен динамический массив строк.
Создаю его таким образом:

```
string *keySeq = new string[];
int strCounter = 0;
```

Далее в коде ругается на эту строчку:

```
keySeq[strCounter] = "";
```

> ОС Windows инициировала точку останова в FruitFly.exe.
>
> Это может быть вызвано повреждением кучи и указывает на ошибку в
>   FruitFly.exe или в одной из загруженных им DLL.

Что тут не так?
MS Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 8):

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"Hello", "World"};
```

Поддержка инициализации неагрегатных типов через синтаксис с фигурными скобками была добавлена только с выходом стандарта `C++11` (в [GCC 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) и  в [Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable)).

Comment: О, ок, спасибо.

Comment: Поддержка массивов строк имеет место быть уже черти сколько лет. Массивы строк ничем не отличаются от других массивов. `std::initializer_list` был добавлен недавно, да. Но это совершенно другое.

Comment: @ixSci речь о инициализации неагрегатных типов (таких как `std::vector`). Вероятно, это имел в виду @dDevil.

Comment: @alexolut, я понял, что он имел ввиду(поэтому и написал про initializer_list), но нужно написать правильно, а не так, чтобы можно было только догадываться, о чём идёт речь. В настоящей формулировке ответ не верен и, по существу, должен иметь -4, а не +4.

Comment: @ixSci код и подход верный, а описание сейчас подправим :)

Answer (score 5):

Если используется `std::string`, то логично и дальше использовать стандартные типы, например, `std::vector`, как уже было предложено @dDevil. Это наиболее правильный подход.

По коду, который написан изначально, можно сказать, что он:

- не соответствует Стандарту C++;
- содержит неопределенное поведение (UB).

При вызове `operator new[]` должен быть передан размер массива. Запись без явного указания размера разрешена в visual C++, но это запрещено Стандартом. В данном случае запись `new string[]` интерпретируется как `new string[0]`. Т.е. массив из нуля элементов. При этом, как известно, в массиве разрешено обращаться только к элементам с индексами не меньше 0 и меньше размера массива. Т.к. массив пустой, элементов, к которым можно обращаться, просто не существует. Чтобы приведенный код, не порождал ошибку, нужно как минимум добавить ненулевую размерность при выделении памяти для массива:

```
string *keySeq = new string[size];
```

где size - целое положительное число, задающее максимальное кол-во элементов массива.

Comment: где size - целое положительное число, отличное от нуля. К сожалению, в С++ ноль это положительное число)

Comment: судя по Вашему ответу, я не могу обращаться по нулевому индексу. Исправьте пожалуйста

Comment: @rikimaru2013 где сказано, что ноль положительное число?